# media queries not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

I am trying to learn mediaqueries and I need some help.

My code is not working in IE8

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-size:11em;
    color:#000;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
body {
        font-size:5em;
        color:#ff0000;
  }
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<body>
az a s d a sd
</body>
```

Please suggest, what should I do to make it run in IE8 or lesser? I added **css3-mediaqueries.js** in `</head>` section (you can see code mentioned below) but it's not helping me.

```
<!-- css3-mediaqueries.js for IE less than 9 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a server? I suspect IE8 won't load the external javascript if it's running locally.

Comment: i had run this code on both locally and on server but it not working

Comment: Have you tried using a local copy of the JS code? Are there any error messages in the console? What other debugging steps have you taken? Do the media queries work in other browsers that support them natively (IE9, FF, etc)? Is your HTML in standards mode (i.e. does it have a doctype?) and does it validate? Have you included the viewport metatag (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`) and CSS (`@-ms-viewport{ width: device-width; } @-o-viewport { width: device-width; } @viewport { width: device-width; }`)? Can you put up a JSFiddle showing your work so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If css3-mediaqueries.js wont work - try [Respond](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). Just keep this as a note as well for using CSS3-mediaqueries.js - it's from their [site](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) ->

> Note: Doesn't work on @import'ed stylesheets (which you shouldn't use
>   anyway for performance reasons). Also won't listen to the media
>   attribute of the `<link>` and `<style>` elements.

Comment: Just to be clear - you are speaking about the Media Queries right - NOT the transitions.